# How to use a vector argument for a function generated by matlabFunction

Tags: function, matlab, arguments, symbolic-math, function-handle

When I run the following Matlab code:

```
x=sym('x',[2 1])    
func=x.'*x    
f=matlabFunction(func)    
x=rand(2,1)    
f(x(1),x(2))     % this works    
f(x)             % but this gives an error
```

I get an error:

```
Error using symengine>makeFhandle/@(x1,x2)x1.^2+x2.^2
Not enough input arguments.
```

I want to make the code more general for an n-vector, with n determined in the code.
Therefore I cannot list all n variables like `f(x(1), x(2), ..., x(n))`
Is there a way to convert the n-vector into a list of n components to be passed to the function?

Answer (score 4):

There's a trick you can use with [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html).  What you would do is convert each parameter into its own individual cell, then use the `:` to deal out the parameters.  In other words, you would do this:

```
x = rand(2,1);
c = num2cell(x);
f(c{:})
```

Repeating your code above, and using what I have defined, this is what I get:

```
%// Your code
x=sym('x',[2 1]);    
func=x.'*x;    
f=matlabFunction(func);    
x=rand(2,1);

%// My code
c = num2cell(x);

%// Display what x is
x

%// Display what the output is
out = f(c{:})
```

I am also displaying what `x` is and what the final answer is.  This is what I get:

```
x =

    0.1270
    0.9134

out =

    0.8504
```

This is also the same as:

```
out = f(x(1), x(2))

out =

    0.8504
```

---

In general, you can do this with any dimensional vector you want, provided that your function you're defining can handle that many inputs / dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, use the `vars` parameter:

```
f=matlabFunction(func,'vars',{x})
p=rand(2,1)
f(p)
```