# Vector inputs when converting symbolic expression to function handle

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, function-handle

I have a symbolic ODE:

```
syms x1 x2 cs ks ms t2 real
xx=[x1 x2];   
fun_sym=[xx(2); (cs/ms)*(xx(1)^2-1)*xx(2) - (ks/ms)*xx(1)];
```

I want to solve it using ODE function, but first I need to convert it into function handle:

```
v=matlabFunction(fun_sym,'vars', [t2,xx,cs,ks,ms]);
[T,x]= ode15s(@(t2,xx) v,t,[1 0]);
```

where `t=[0:0.1:1]`. Matlab gives an error:

```
@(T2,XX)V returns a vector of length 1, but the length of initial conditions vector is 2.
```

I think this is because it interpret v as: `@(t2,x1,x2,cs,ks,ms)`, so it expects the second argument to be `x1`, which is a 1-by-1 element, even though I have defined v as `[t2,xx,...]`, where `xx` is a 1-by-2 element. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26223071/7328782

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but you need to give values to the other parameters as well (`cs`, `ks`, and `ms`)

```
v=matlabFunction(fun_sym,'vars', [t2,x1,x2,cs,ks,ms]);
[T,x]= ode15s(@(t2,xx) v(t2,xx(1),xx(2),cs,ks,ms),t,[1 0]);
```

Comment: Perfect. Is there any way I can pass a vector instead of having x1, x2? This didn't work: 
`v=matlabFunction(f,'vars', {t2,xx,cs,ks});
[T,x]= ode15s(@(t2,xx) v(t2,xx,1,1),t,[1 0]);`

Comment: No. I don;t think there's any way of doing that in Matlab, due to the way symbolic arrays are treated. But I can't see any reason why it could be a problem not to be able to do so.